# Determine an 8-SOIC MOSFET for boosting current capability

Tags: mosfet

I am a complete electronics newbie.

I recently designed a set of PCBs for LED tail lights. I have a sequence controller for them that can can control 28 channels at 260 mA. What I want to do is boost the current on only a single channel. I know I can boost a single channel with a single P-channel MOSFET and some resistors. What I really want to do is redesign my board to use something in a 8-SOIC package and maybe a bit more efficient. I know it can be done I just don’t know how to calculate what 8-SOIC package I would need to accomplish my goal. The image below the schematic shows a board with the ICs I’m looking for but I can’t make out the numbers. There are 28 channels (inputs) and 14 ICs that convert each input to 3 A max output. There are also resistors on the bottom of that board but I can’t make those out either.

To recap:

- I want to boost a (or multiple) 12 V 260 mA ground switched control channel(s) to a max of 3 A.
- I want to use an 8-SOIC package to accomplish integration into my board design to keep components and form factor smaller.

[image: Here is my current setup]

28 260 mA ground switched inputs boosted to 28 3 A outputs. This is not my board. I would like to integrate these ICs into my board design.

[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is called "dual n-channel mosfet soic-8". Plug that phrase into your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a formula for determining which one to use and which resistor values to use?

Comment: No. You match up the specifications to your application's requirements, just like with anything else.

Comment: 3A seems like a lot to drive an LED. Can you LEDs actually take that much current? I also expect your MOSFETs would get pretty hot.

Comment: Well the LEDs on my current board only draw about 160ma (max) per channel in its current iteration. One circuit may draw more than the 260ma max (per channel, total of 28 channels) that the controller is rated for per channel. I’m waiting for a separate led array to arrive to check the current draw. I just wanted something I could integrate into future designs without having to design another component pcb to add on. If I knew more about electronics, components, and design I would just integrate the micro controllers directly into the board design.

Comment: @hekete  You cannot "guess" how hot the FET gets until you know the switching frequency. With under half-milliohm RdsOn devices available the continuous dissipated power can be as low as 45 micro-Watt.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the board pictured and assuming those are dual n-channel chips, it likely works something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fucYAS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At least, I think this is how it would work? It doesn't really seem suitable for 3A to me...

R1 and R2 form a voltage divider on M1s Gate. R3 is feed back.

The only formula you need for any of this is Ohms Law. The only specs that super matter for your components are obviously voltage, current and power dissipation being within your operating requirements.

There is no reason to copy that design though. It has some drawbacks, like being dependent on the input voltage. If your input voltage changes then so does the current, in fact a small voltage change will result in a large current change. I expect it also gets quite hot.

Comment: I am here to learn. Everything you guys are giving me is helping.

Comment: The circuit above doesn’t appear to be correct though. Each channel of the of the dual channel mosfet is controlled independently. I know 3A is a lot but I just wanted quite a bit of wiggle room in the event I wanted to use something more high powered.

Comment: Oh you're right, I will change the circuit. It's just the paired solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

> One circuit may draw more than the 260ma max (per channel, total of 28 channels) that the controller is rated for per channel.

I imagine that's because there are two or more LEDs in parallel. Just put them on separate channels - that way you have more control too, if needed.